# Idiomatic Clojure

Tags: clojure, coding-style

I'm about a week in to Clojure and functional programming in general—all of my background is in OOP. I'd like to take advantage of Clojure's much-tauted legibility and inherent logic, but right now I don't know if I'm doing that successfully and just not wrapping my mind around it completely, or if I really am  abusing the language in a bad way.

For example:

```
(ns waterfall-quiz.response-parser
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn process-input
  [input]
  (finalize-input
    (normalize-height
      (map-input
        (numberize-vector
          (vectorize-input
            (clean-input input)))))))

(defn clean-input
  "Removes extraneous whitespace."
  [input]
  (clojure.string/replace input #"\s+" " "))

(defn vectorize-input
  "Turns input into a vector."
  [input]
  (clojure.string/split input #"\s"))

(...)
```

I'm very suspicious of the process-input function, which calls all the other functions to format some input. It is referentially transparent, but it seems so brittle—is there a smarter way to chain all of the functions together?

Another example:

```
(defn map-builder
  "Transforms the vector of waterfalls into a map of waterfalls."
  [vectorized-db]
  (assoc waterfall-db
  (keyword (str 'waterfall (first (re-seq #"[0-9]+" (str (first vectorized-db))))))
  (subs (str (first vectorized-db)) (+ 2 (.indexOf (str (first vectorized-db)) ":")))))
```

I was losing track of where I was in the parentheses constantly while writing that function—should it be broken up into smaller functions?

Comment: I suggest you move this post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `(finalize-input (normalize-height (map-input (numberize-vector (vectorize-input (clean-input input))))))` is the same as `(-> input clean-input vectorize-input numberize-vector map-input normalize-height finalize-input)`, but the latter is much easier to read and to modify.

Comment: Mike, check out 4clojure.com. Try getting through all the easy and medium examples at least and reviewing the solutions of top 10 players (not mine!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two idiomatic tools Clojure that would most improve your code are the `let` and `->` macros.

[`let`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let) allows you to build up local bindings incrementally

[`->`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E) chains together a series of function calls in a more readable and easier to edit form

```
(defn process-input
  [input]
  (-> input
      clean-input
      vectorize-input
      numberize-vector
      map-input
      normalize-height
      finalize-input))

(defn map-builder
  "Transforms the vector of waterfalls into a map of waterfalls."
  [waterfall-db vectorized-db]
  (let [key-str (str (first vectorized-db))
        key (->> key-str
                 (re-seq #"[0-9]+")
                 first
                 (str 'waterfall)
                 keyword)
        val (subs key-str (+ 2 (.indexOf key-str ":")))]
    (assoc waterfall-db key val)))
```

I also took the liberty of making `waterfall-db` an arg to map-builder so it can be used more easily in functional code (perhaps with the help of `swap!`, `reduce` or `update-in`).